# jQuery getJSON with .NET MVC not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have setup a getJSON call when page loads in my .NET MVC app like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("/Administrator/GetAllUsers", function (res) {

            // getting internal server error here...
        });

});
```

And the action looks like this:

```
  [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetAllUsers")]
    public string GetAllUsers()
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ctx.zsp_select_allusers().ToList());
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What am I doing wrong here???

Comment: `return Json(ctx.zsp_select_allusers(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Remove the slash / before Administrator/GetAllUsers and check. Your return type should be JsonReturn

Comment: And its needs to be `public ActionResult GetAllUsers()` or `public JsonResult GetAllUsers()`

Comment: @BasantaMatia still not working :/

Comment: @StephenMuecke Gonna check it out now :D

Comment: @StephenMuecke should I defer the query and dump the data into the memory with ToList() or ?

Comment: There is no need for `.ToList()` (its being serialized, so therefore the collection is being iterated)

Comment: @StephenMuecke amazing thx =) gonna try it this way now

Comment: @StephenMuecke still getting internal server error even with allowget behaviour ... :/

Comment: Then you need to show us what `ctx.zsp_select_allusers()` is (the code in your controller is throwing an exception - possibly because your model contains a property which is a model and that contains a property which is the original model - a circular reference). And use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response - it will give you the details of the error

Comment: @StephenMuecke the worst thing is, it works on my local host, and when I upload the code to the server it fails, it still shows internal error 500... o.O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139964/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user987).

Answer (score 1):

Change your return type in method and return Json, like bellow,

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetAllUsers")]
public ActionResult GetAllUsers()
{
    var data = ctx.zsp_select_allusers().ToList();
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As you have mentioned in your comment, you are still getting 500 error. I think this controller have **[Authorize]** attribute and you are calling this method without login. In this case you can use **[AllowAnonymous]** attribute in GetAllUsers() to access the method.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, json result only returned if you make `post` request to it for some security purposes, until and unless you explicitly specify `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`, also change your return type

```
[HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetAllUsers")]
    public JsonResult GetAllUsers()
    {
        return Json(ctx.zsp_select_allusers(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: It's silly but try to remove `[HttpGet]` and `[ActionName("GetAllUsers")]`

Comment: If still you get the error, edit your question and paste code of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetAllUsers", "Administrator")', function (res)   {

            alert(res);
        });

 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAllUsers( ) {

          //get the data from db , then send it
          //i'm passing dummy text 'got it'

        return Json("got it", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```