# Retrieve data from controller and return to ajax call failing

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following ajax call in my view:

```
var obj = { maintId: id };

$.ajax({
    url:  '@Url.Action("EditLog" ,"Maintenance")',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: obj,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
    alert(data.Reason); 
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

It hits the Action (`EditLog`) just fine but not able to return the values for `SystemID` and Reason to the ajax call success data area.

Note that I will be putting values from the DB but for testing, I put hard coded values for `SystemID` and `Reason`. When I run the code it goes to the error: function section and I get a parsererror.  I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditLog(int maintId)
{        
    return Json(new { SystemID = 1233, Reason = "ReagDegree change" });     
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `obj` which you are passing to `data:` of `ajax`? Also, why are you using `async:false`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery getJSON with .NET MVC not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229760/jquery-getjson-with-net-mvc-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as well:

```
return Json(new { SystemID = 1233, Reason = "ReagDegree change" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The `JsonRequestBehavior` Enum:

> Specifies whether HTTP GET requests from the client are allowed.

Which by default is set to `Deny get`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2